# Email With Attachment for Gmail

Tags: php, email

Following is my piece of code which I am using to send email with attachment. The code works fine if i send email to hotmail or outlook's account but the code doesnot work when I send email to gmail's account. I receive email on gmail but there is rubbish written on the email something like following. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue for gmail.

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_x9e353014396812b52f548f23d8c48987x
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

MY MESSAGE HTML CODE HERE

--==Multipart_Boundary_x9e353014396812b52f548f23d8c48987x
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
 name="Newsroom image.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7QB4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAFwcAmcAUDUz
NjE2Yzc0NjU2NDVmNWY5YzhiN2RjYWM5ZWIyNGFjODk4ZTQ3M2E5ZTY4N2Q1MGNmZmE5NDZlYzdj
NGM1NzkwZDVhN2UwY2VkNjQ3Y
```

**CODE - Headers**

```
// Now Generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
   $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";
    // Now we'll build the message headers
          $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
             "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
             "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
             " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
             $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

          // Next, we'll build the message body note that we insert two dashes in front of the  MIME boundary when we use it
          $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
             "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
             "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
             "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
             $message . "\n\n";

          // Now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as an attachment, then add the file content and set another boundary to indicate that the end of the file has been reached
          $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
             "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
             " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
             //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
             //" file=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
             $data . "\n\n" .
             "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Comment: I *highly* suggest not building emails yourself.  Try something pre-made like: http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: I can only underline what @RocketHazmat said. There is easy to use existing code that will do the job. No need to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: At one point I was trying to do the same thing you are and I wasted about 4 hours, which I will never get back. I found **[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)** and I've never looked back, it is **DEAD-SIMPLE**. Even if you don't use it yourself, you seem smart enough that you could pick apart the code and apply it to your situation. Good luck!

Comment: @ALL hanks for your comments I used PHPmailer and everything is working fine now